# SQL MAX() question

Tags: sql, max

```
uid     timestamp
1   1242420497
1   1243534661
1   1243534858
1   1243611312
1   1243611511
3   1244817764
3   1244819093
1   1244749446
```

I have this table, and I am lookng to grab the row that has the highest time stamp.
I tried using

```
SELECT uid,max(timestamp) FROM `node_revisions` WHERE nid=51
```

but that returned

```
uid timestamp
1   1244819093
```

which has the wrong uid as you can see. How would I make it grab the uid from the correct row? thanks

Comment: you condition is searching for nid...did you mean to put uid there?

Comment: this is not a SQL MAX question. Just order by timestamp DESC and pick the first one. See my solution below.

Comment: Using aggregate functions without a GROUP BY clause should be forbidden - and is in T-SQL.

Comment: @David: Then the OP must be using either MySQL or SQLite, which permit ambiguous use of GROUP BY.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT uid, timestamp 
FROM node_revisions 
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM node_revisions);
```

**Updated** per Ryan Oberoi's comment; since we're getting just the one record, MAX() in the outer query is unnecessary.  Thanks.

Comment: thanks, that seems to work. I just added that NID field to it to meet my needs, but it got the job done

Comment: do not need the MAX in the first select... simpler to use ORDER BY timestamp DESC...

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT
    uid,
    max(timestamp) as max_time
FROM
    node_revisions
WHERE
    nid = 51
GROUP BY
    uid
ORDER BY 
    max_time DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @op: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @OP: You could add "ORDER BY max_time DESC LIMIT 1" to the SQL to prevent more than one UID from coming back.

Answer (score 5):

SELECT * FROM `node_revisions` WHERE nid=51 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 2):

first thing, `nid` does not appear in your table.

second, I suspect you want `group by uid`

Answer (score 2):

Your example uses nid=51 instead of uid=51.  Is this code copied directly from what you're running?  If there is a nid field, this may be your issue.  And you need a group by clause.

```
SELECT uid, max(timestamp) as max_time
FROM 'node_revisions'
WHERE uid = 51
GROUP BY uid
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work just fine..im sure

```
select uid FROM `node_revisions`
WHERE uid=51 and timestamp = (select max(timestamp) where uid = 51)
group by uid
```